# Нужно ли в данном примере выделять запятыми вводную часть "судя по всему" с двух сторон?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Я слышал, как кричала та нянька.  И, судя по всему, не на тебя.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*И судя по всему, не на тебя.*

[ПУНКТУАЦИЯ ПРИ ВВОДНЫХ СЛОВАХ И СОЧЕТАНИЯХ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2)

> Вводное слово обычно не отделяется знаком препинания от присоединительного союза, стоящего в начале предложения. ***Да кроме того**, он уже и сделал кое-что путное.* Д. Гранин, Зубр.
>
> **Примечание**. При интонационном выделении вводного слова оно может отделяться запятой от союза: ***Но, к великой моей досаде**, Швабрин, обыкновенно снисходительный, решительно объявил, что песня моя нехороша.* А. Пушкин, Капитанская дочка.

Таким образом, если в речи есть пауза (или автор текста хочет показать заминку говорящего), то возможен и вариант с обособлением с двух сторон.